# Deno oak server post body and reponse

Tags: post, deno, oak

I use oak server with Deno. But there is some problem with the response in post request.
My example:

```
const loginEp = async (ctx, next) => {//loginEp
  if(!ctx.request.hasBody) {//if
    ctx.throw(415);
  }//if
  
  const reqBody = await ctx.request.body({ type: 'json' }).value;
 
  console.log(reqBody, typeof reqBody);
 
  ctx.response.status = 200;
  ctx.response.body = {key_one: "One"};
  ctx.response.type = "json";

 };//loginEp

const router = new Router()
router.post("/api/login", loginEp)

app.use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(router.routes());
```

Try use:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request POST \
     --data '{"login":"test","password":"test123"}' \
     http://localhost:8010/api/login
```

The server receives the request and prints the body to the console. But I am not getting a response from the server.

If comment `const reqBody = await ctx.request.body({ type: 'json' }).value; console.log(reqBody, typeof reqBody);` then I get response.

I can't understand how to get the request body on the server and respond.

Answer (score 1):

"value" on the body is also a promise, try awaiting it:

`const reqBody = await (await ctx.request.body({ type: 'json' })).value;`